# Best practice to recover an CRUD statement to a linked server if connection is lost

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, service-broker, transactional-replication

I am looking for the best practice for the following scenario.

We have a CRM in our company. When an employee updates the record of a company, there is trigger that fires a stored procedure which has a CRUD statement to the linked server hosting the SQL DB of our website.

---

Question:

What happens when the connection is lost in the middle of the CRUD and the SQL DB of the website did not get updated? What would be the best way to have the SQL statement processed again when the connection is back?

I read about Service Broker or Transactional Replication. Is one of these more appropriate for that situation?

---

The configuration:

Local: SQL server 2008 R2

Website: SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of handling it, assuming that the CRUD statement isn't modal, in the sense that you have to give a response from the linked server to the user before anything else can happen:

The trigger stores, in a local table, all the meta-information you need to run the CRUD statement on the linked server.

A job runs every n minutes that reads the table, attempts to do the CRUD statements stored in the table, and flags them as done if the linked server returns any kind of success message.  The ones that aren't successful stay as they are in the table until the next time the job runs.

Comment: Thanks tab. I am considering this solution as a potential plan C. "C" because from what I read about `service broker` and `transactional replication`, they both have some sort of built in queue and job running in background etc... "Potential" because I don't know much about it and my plan C might turn into in plan A.

Comment: Would it be a better practice than using `Service Broker`, or faster or safer?

Comment: Oh I'm not at all familiar with Service Broker, so I couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction failed in the middle of the trigger it would still be in the transaction and the data would not be written to either the CRM database or the web database. There is also the potential problem of performance, the SQL server data modification query wouldn't return control to the client until both the local and remote change had completed. The latter wouldn't be a problem if the query was executed async, but fire and forget isn't a good pattern for writing data.

Service Broker would allow you to write the modification into some binary data and take care of ensuring that it was delivered in order and properly processed at the remote end. Performance would not be so bad as the insert into the queue is designed to be completed quickly returning control to the trigger and allowing the original CRM query to complete.

However, it is quite a bit to set up. Even using service broker for simple tasks on a local server takes quite a bit of setup, partly because it is designed to handle secure, multicast, reliable ordered conversations so it needs a few layers to work. Once it is all there is is very reliable and does a lot of the work you would otherwise have to do to set up this sort of distributed conversation.

I have used it in the past to create a callback system from a website, a customer enters their number on the site and requests a callback this is sent via service broker over a VPN from the web to the back office server and a client application waits for a call on the service broker queue. Worked very efficiently once it was set up.

Comment: Thanks webturner. So if I summarize correctly, Service Broker would be a better option overall but more complicated to set up? I spent the last few days trying to have it work on our test environment. I just got it to work. I now have to try with triggers, SP and updates stuffed in it. But it seems very strong so far.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The trigger should just call call the send with the parameters in the data. The SP should be run using message activation to and receive the parameters. You also need to ensure you finish the conversation from both ends and deal with poison messages, i.e. those that have been retried too many times and have been removed from the queue to unblock it.